# I added a mail account to Outlook using imap and now want to sync the agenda to iphone, is this possible?

Tags: outlook, imap, synchronization, iphone

Currently I have the mail account added to both Outlook and iphone using the same imap/smtp settings.

When I add and verify the account on iPhone in "Settings -> Mail, contacts, calendars" the only sync options it allows me to select are:

Mail
Notes

There's no option to sync an agenda like when you add an Exchange mail account.

Is it possible to do this at all? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) is an Internet standard protocol used by e-mail clients to retrieve e-mail messages from a mail server over a TCP/IP connection as defined by RFC 3501.

If you wish to sync contacts & calendar entries you need to use WebDAV (CalDAV, CardDAV).

So as you have only IMAP configured on the device it allows you only to select "mail".